# Sending an email with python using csv data for the body

Tags: python, csv, email

I am using the csv library to pull data to into an email body. I am pulling certain columns from the csv for the body. I am using a junk gmail account to test. I'm just confused on how to use the for loop. If I'm correct, you need a for loop to read the rows then a for loop to email out. I did read [Reading and Writing CSV Files](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) but was uncertain how to implement it with smtplib.

```
import csv, smtplib, ssl

message = """Subject: Your Title

{supervisor} {title} {start}"""

from_address = "test@gmail.com"
password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(from_address, password)
    with open('test.csv','rb') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
        next(reader)

            #start = []
            #title = []
            #supervisor = []

            for row in reader:
                title = row[3]
                start = row[0]
                supervisor = row[4]

            for supervisor, title, start in reader:
                 server.sendmail(
                    from_address,
                     Email,
                     message.format(supervisor=supervisor, start=start, title=title)
                 )

print('Emails were sent successfully!')
```

CSV File:

```
StartDate,Employee Name,PC,Title,Supervisor Name,email 
12/9/2019,Katti M. Ricke,289,Recruiter,Courtney Clark,test@gmail.com
```

Comment: have you example of your csv ? ..

Comment: I added it up top

Comment: I have example using pandas and io ...it work

Answer (score 3):

Probably if you use pandas for to handle the csv could be more easy ..for install pandas just pip install pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# read csv using pandas and then convert the csv to html string ....this code later will add into body
str_io = io.StringIO()
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.to_html(buf=str_io)
table_html = str_io.getvalue()
print(table_html)


sender_email = "mymail@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "anothermail@gmail.com"
password = "mypass"

message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message["Subject"] = "Subject: Your Title"
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email

text = """\
Subject: Your Title"""

html = """\
<html>
  <body>
    <p>{table_html}</p>
  </body>
</html>
""".format(table_html=table_html)

part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")
message.attach(part1)
message.attach(part2)

# Send email
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(
        sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string()
    )
```